# Can we change text size by changing Font Type in Win-11?

Tags: fonts, resolution, windows-11, accessibility

I have tried hard to change text size in Win-11 using Accesibilty & slider & in Display using Scale & combinations of both.

But still it is too small & it doesn't much change Title Bar Font Or Menu bar Font or Icons Text etc etc.

I also see numerous posts everywhere on internet for the same problem & all answers are same as above.

So I was reading about Changing the Type of Fonts themselves e.g. from default Segoe UI to something like Verdana or Arial or Calibri etc. There it also gives you the choice of font size as large as you want just like in MS Word.

So my question is, is this the better solution ?

I don't have Windows -11 any more so I can't try it out myself but I am ordering a new system & wondering whether I shoud get it with Win-11 or Win-10 ?

Thank You

Comment: You can always switch to a lower resolution, which will make everything bigger.

Comment: Make Text Size Bigger works on Windows 10 and 11 and text can enlarge to over 200% .  Not a font issue with respect to size.

Comment: No, I am not talking about font type but the size of font & more clearly the size of text. If i increase the size of text beyond 125% in Win-11, it cuts the lower half of the text so text in Windows explorer & all file & folder names in a drive gets chopped up in half & becomes like somone cut a line of text in half so you cant figure out what it says.